# Redirect all calls to an script without showing the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This a Symfony related issue but I think any one with mod rewrite experience can solve it.

If the user call `myhost.com/somepage` and want him to actually call `myhost.com/app.php/somepage` and this should be true also for ajax calls. Ideally hiding from the url the app.php part.

So far I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ welcomestuff/welcome.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

That just send the user to welcome.php is there is no file with the name REQUEST_FILENAME, how can I modify it in order to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: are you 100% sure of this? Im getting 404 on pages that I know are there when im not using the app.php on the url

Comment: @DomingoSL if a request is for a file or directory that exists, one of the two conditions will fail. Unless this is all in a directory that's not the document root, you may need to leave off the leading `/`.

Comment: my apache is set to use /var/www/web as the root directory, does it changes something?

Comment: @DomingoSL as long as `app.php` is in your document root and your server is setup to handle path info (executes app.php and passes the rest as "PATH_INFO"). With that setup, the above rule works for me in a blank htaccess file in document root